Running NetworkManager.service after reaching graphical.target
As per my utter naive understanding of systemd units, one of the services multi-user.target wants completed is NetworkManager.service. Once multi-user.target is achieved, graphical.target which is the default target is executed which executes display-manager.service which in turn executes gdm.
Is it possible to remove "NetworkManager.service" from dependency of multi-user.target and instead execute it from display-manager.service.
What i basically is that startup doesn't wait for networking to come up and once login screen is reached, NetworkManager.service is executed so that networking is initialized parallel to while the user is logging in.
There might be usecases of running networking during Startup but I can't fathom any such usecase for a normal desktop user like me.

...until the day your Desktop breaks due to an ill-advised extension or application, and suddenly you also have no network available. Repair sometimes becomes much more difficult if apt cannot download packages.
